# Wait for the stored procedure to wait for the execution of other stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How can I run SQL Server stored procedures one after another in sequence?

I would like the procedure to wait for termination before the next one is executed.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like described here?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/00ab0007-e46f-4047-b758-e0ab1c56e84c

Comment: Ok Well it still does not answer if the 2nd execute will not happen till the first one is done. How can i confirm this?

Comment: From the thread linked:  "SQL Server can split singe query into multiple treads, but it will not run consecutive commands from one session in parallel."   So if you make another stored procedure that calls each of yours, they will execute sequentially.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it would really benefit from quoting the relevant bits of the linked thread in the answer